# Create install package. Monodevelop. openSuse 13.1

Tags: c#, monodevelop, opensuse

How I can create install package of my project in monodevelop, which was written in monodevelop C#? Help  me please.

Comment: Why do you write such a comment? Did I not clearly written on top. Why rub every game ?. Go somewhere else

Comment: Do you plan to create installers for which operating systems?

Comment: I recommend you to use `Open Build Service` then